# CSV file upload causing FileNotFoundError on macbook

Tags: python, pandas, macos, dataframe, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file using python on a MacBook. I've tried multiple platforms such as jupyter notebook, google colab and pycharm but none have worked with uploading my csv file.

I tried to use the regular method of `import`ing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/trevorwilliams/Desktop/germany.csv')
print (df)
```

I got:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/trevorwilliams/Desktop/germany.csv'
```

Is there anything I need to change or do with the pathname? I just used the right click and alt/option when copying the pathname before pasting it.

I've also tried to change the characters from backslash to forward slash and inserting two slashes and tried including `/.rb/` after `.csv` to see if that would work but still didn't
and I also tried checking if the OS path existed and it said it was false.

Any suggestions or tips on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show output of `os.path.exists()`?

Comment: An `r` prefix is only needed when paths have backslash separator characters in them. You shouldn't need to use it for them on MacOS. It also looks to me like you're trying to ***read*** the file, not upload or import it — so you might want to change your question accordingly. Also,

Comment: @pavel https://imgur.com/LE3qeS9

Comment: https://imgur.com/m9lQhi3 this is without the "r" in front and just as it is with the regular path copied and pasted

Comment: Can you try `'~/Desktop/germany.csv'` path instead?

Comment: @pavel It still didn't work for me when I checked if it existed or tried to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command to check in which directory you are currently are:

```
import os

os.getcwd()
```

If not in the same directory,
run this command

```
os.chdir(‘/Users/trevorwilliams/Desktop/’)
```

You can then import the CSV using Pandas